# What would someone call their stepfather's deceased wife?

Tags: single-word-requests

- Man 1 and Woman 1 marry. They don't have a child. Woman 1 dies.
- Man 2 and Woman 2 marry. They have a child. Man 2 dies.
- Man 1 and Woman 2 marry. They don't have a child.

What would the child of Man 2 and Woman 2 call Woman 1, if anything?

Comment: My stepfather first deceased wife.

Comment: You have to say she's dead every time you refer to Stepdad's old wife? Does this come up often?

Comment: My stepfather's first wife. Keep it simple.

Comment: "Joan", in everyday conversation. Otherwise provide as much information as needed/relevant. Why are you saying this? Is it in an official form, for genealogical purposes, to friends or relatives, or some other context?

Answer (score 6):

Nothing so difficult to guess.

- She would be referred to as "**my stepfather's first wife**"

  or "my stepfather's late first wife".

Comment: Even if we rule out zombie-philia, "first deceased wife" is not clear. Has he had several wives and of them she was the first to die, or was she his first wife, who is now deceased?

Comment: @Tim   Yes, I agree.  Will try to fix that.

Comment: You can switch the order of the adjectives.